# How to use keyword as an identifier in c?

Tags: c, identifier

I read on a book of C Language "LET US C" that certain keywords can be used as an identifier but i don't know how.
CAN ANY ONE HELP ?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Could you quote the book where it says that "certain keywords can be used as an identifier"?

Comment: I have already mentioned it.

Comment: LET US C by Yashwant Kanetkar.

Comment: It says :"Some C compilers allow you to contruct variable names that exactly resemble the keywords.However,it would be safer /*Not   Necessary */ not to mix up the variable names and keywords".
Under "C Keywords" Page No. 11 - 10th Edition.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to use a keyword as an identifier in C, with the exception of macro names and macro parameters.